# Does Webstorm support autosuggestion for Revealing-Module-Pattern in different Files

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, webstorm

When I try to use the autosuggestion in Webstorm(V 10.0.4/ Linux machine)
with the Revealing-Module-Pattern and the definition of the module is in one File like this:

```
   var testModule = testModule || (function(){
       function myPrivateTestFunction(){
           console.log("test");
       }
       return{
            test: myPrivateTestFunction
       }
    })();
```

in another File I try to call the the function by:

```
testModule.test();
```

it correctly finds the module-object, defined in the other file but doesn't find the function.

If I look at the settings: File->Settings->Javascript 
There is an option called "Weaker type guess for completion".
If I enable this, it indeed shows my desired function testModule.test().
But it also shows all private members of the module and of all other modules, defined somewhere, so this doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature was implemented by the Webstorm Team.
I tested it (in the Early Access Program Version 142.5255).
It works perfectly!
Thanks to the Webstorm-Team who implemented the feature that fast and to lena who created the ticket!

Answer (score 1):

Logged as [WEB-18186](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18186), please vote for it to be notified on updates